# Read newer version of Mathematica file

Tags: system, compatibility

I am not sure if this question is silly, but I have the Mathematica version 12.1 and my friend has the Mathematica version 12.0 and he cannot read my files. How can I save the files in the version 12.1 so that he can read my files in his version 12.0?

Thanks

Comment: That’s odd. I’ve been able to use files from newer versions on my older one; I just received a warning, but the file opened. Of course, I couldn’t use any functions that has been introduced in versions newer than mine.

Comment: I quite often send files made in newer versions to people with older versions. I have to be careful about which functions I use, but have never had a case of someone not being able to read the file. Might be a question for Wolfram?